How to view files on an Android emulator in Visual Studio(MAUI), similar to "Device Explorer" in android studio?
I am working on a mobile app using MAUI and Visual Studio.  I am saving files to the "/data/user/0/..." folder.  In the past I've used Android Studio, and they have a feature that allows you to view all the files in the emulator called Device Explorer.  How do I access /data/user/0/ folder from Android?
I haven't been able to find a way to view the files stored on the emulator in Visual Studio.  Do you know if Visual Studio has a built-in way to access the data on an emulator?  Thanks
Edit:
I ended up using ADB and command prompt. But I guess you can also use android studio device explore as well(even for apps written in VS).

use adb or Android Studio

The Android Studio device explorer works for all apps that have the flag android:debuggable=true. It doesn't matter how the app was built, only this flag matters. If you want to understand how Device Explorer works on adb level see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72423005/150978

The wording of the question seems confused. maui is a framework for writing apps. You would write your app in an IDE like Visual Studio, vscode, Android Studio, XCode, etc. and I'm not sure if the OP is clearly separating the two.

Thanks everyone. I ended up using adb.

As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)

Yes, we can use Android Debug Bridge (adb) to access the files on android emulators.
First, we need to root the emulator with the following commands:
1    adb devices
2    adb shell   ( adb -s emulator-xxxx shell)
3    exit
4    adb root   (result: restarting adbd as root)
5    adb shell 

Then we can view the files by commands:
  ls -l 
  cd <some folder>
  ls

And we can also access the database with sqlite3 commands:
 cd data/data/<your-package-name>/files/

 sqlite3  <your-db-name>.db

 .tables    ( display tables list)

run sqlite3 commands that you like, eg:
  Select * from table1 where ...;

 

