debugging expo file system files with adb
I'd like to have a look at the files I'm generating with expo-file-system while developing with expo go.
When I run the following
console.log(FileSystem.documentDirectory);

I get a listing of /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files but if I try to go there (or anywhere in /data/user) in adb shell I get a Permissions Error
What is the best way to view the files that I'm generating? Should I build the app and adb push it?
Thanks

If the app has the debug table flag you can use Android Studio device explorer for accessing app private files. Internally it uses run-as command to bypass the permission denied problem. See may answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72418212/150978

Ah cool - thanks for the answer. I tried using run-as but wasn't sure how to get it to work with expo go during development.

As I wrote I recommend using the Android Studio integrated device Explorer tool. It can be used for any debuggable app, no matter how it was developed, even completely outside of Android Studio.
